# $M_1 \oplus R \simeq M_2 \oplus R$ and $M_1 \not\simeq M_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, integral-domain

I have the following problem:

We had to prove that if $R$ is a principal ideal domain we can "subtract" $R$ in direct sums of $R$-modules, i.e. $M_1 \oplus R \simeq M_2 \oplus R$ implies $M_1 \simeq M_2$.

Moreover we had the theorem that if $R$ is commutative (and not necessarily a PID) the rank of free R-modules is well-defined and had an example that this is not true for non-commutative rings. In particular, we obtain a counter example for above if $R$ is not commutative.

> I now wonder if there is an example of a commutative ring $R$ and $R$-modules $M_1, M_2$ such that $M_1 \oplus R \simeq M_2 \oplus R$ but $M_1 \not\simeq M_2$. In particular I wonder if there are integral domains and principal ideal rings which don't fulfill this property.

Comment: Wait, isn't this claim NOT true for $\mathbb{Z}$ (without finite generation hypotheses)?

Comment: @AlexYoucis: By Walker's Cancellation Theorem, $\mathbb{Z}$ is cancellable in the category of abelian groups, i.e. $A \oplus \mathbb{Z} \cong B \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ implies $A \cong B$ for all abelian groups $A,B$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two $R$-modules $M,N$ are said to be stably isomorphic, if there is some $k \geq 0$ such that $M \oplus R^k \cong N \oplus R^k$. $M$ is stably free, if $M \oplus R^k$ is free for some $k$. So you are looking for modules which are stably isomorphic without being isomorphic. In particular, any stably free module which is not free would suffice.

In [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.210.8054&rep=rep1&type=pdf), Keith Conrad gives an example of a stably free module $M$ which is not free: Let $R$ be the integral domain $\mathbb{R}[x,y,z]/(x^2+y^2+z^2-1)$, and $M = \{(a,b,c) \in R^3 : xa + yb + zc = 0\}$. Then $M \oplus R \cong R^3$ but $M \not \cong R^2$.

Comment: Thanks, this at least answers one part of the question, there are integral domains for which this is not true. What about principal ideal rings which are not integral domains?

Comment: I can't remember how many times I've seen this example (which belongs to Hochster, btw) on M.SE!

Comment: @user26857 do you know a reference of Hochster where he introduced that example of a stably free module?